INVALID_SESSION_ID with metadata api login
I'm trying the metadata api in java using this sample code - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_java_sample.htm
Instead of the basic authentication using username password, i have setup a connected app using jwt (code here - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5)
But when i use the access token got from oauth in the metadata login like config.setSessionId(token) i get an INVALID_SESSION_ID error. Any thoughts on why this could happen?
Below is the failing code
final ConnectorConfig metadataConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
            metadataConfig.setManualLogin(true);
            metadataConfig.setServiceEndpoint("https://mysandboxname.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/60.0/orgId");
            metadataConfig.setSessionId(token.toString());
            return new MetadataConnection(metadataConfig);

